# I won't accept my Ex-Employer new offer

Tags: job-offer, job-change

Before I leave my previous job, my ex-boss told me that I could call him at any time.

I am not very thrilled about my new job, so I contacted him and he seems willing to hire me back, except that he won't propose anything better (I will work in the same conditions + I shouldn't leave again, at least not very quickly).

It's obvious for me right now that I won't accept his offer, especially after a short interview we had this week.

He said he will have to convince departments to accept me back, especially that there was some Veto when I was hired the previous time.

It looks like he is working on preparing my comeback.

Should I anticipate and tell my ex-boss I am not interested anymore?

Or should I wait for his call and then tell him?

Answer (score 9):

Bad news does not get better with time! Especially if your ex-boss will be sticking his neck out for you to hire you back, **tell him ASAP**.

Since you already know you won't take the offer, you'll just be wasting his time going around convincing people to accept you back. You don't want to make him look foolish or annoy him for wasted effort and damage that relationship.

Comment: +1. If the company as a whole was unsure about you first time around then they will be doubly so this time, in that you're now a clear flight risk. Your boss is going to use up a lot of political capital on this effort on your behalf and it would be thoroughly unfair to let him waste it.

Comment: @JuliaHayward, just to let know I have proven that I was a good fit for the position, and beyond. The HR lady was wrong due to some ideology mismatch or something, and everyone in every department knows how I made things move forward in my department.

Answer (score 0):

> Or should I wait for his call and then tell him?

If you are certain that your previous employer won't come back with something you can't refuse, then you should indicate that you aren't interested. That way, you don't waste any more of your time and don't waste their time.

There were reasons why you left before. Those reasons seldom change. Usually, it doesn't work out if you were to go back.

Comment: +1 for noting that there were reasons why OP left in the first place and that those reasons will not change. I think that's key.